# How to get full screen click event in HTML 5 Video tag player

Tags: html, html5-video

I need to get the full screen click event of the HTML 5 video tag player.
By using any javascript or jquery method.
Can anyone please help me in solving this issue.

[image: Video PLayer]

Thanks.

Comment: Funny thing is that, since I switched my youtube preferences to play as HTML5, the full-screen button for embed videos is gone :(

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function () {
     console.log(document.fullscreen);
}, false);
document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function () {
     console.log(document.mozFullScreen);
}, false);
document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function () {
     console.log(document.webkitIsFullScreen);
}, false);
```

Comment: @longilong... sorry i can't able to get that event by using your code.

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble using the `fullscreenchange` event on a `video` tag as the handler did not trigger in Chrome, but did have success with using a [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) and checking the full screen element:

```
let ro = new ResizeObserver((entries)=>{
  if(document.fullscreenElement == myVideoId){
    alert(`myVideoId element is fullscreen`)
  }
})
ro.observe(myVideo)
```

Here's a [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/sweaver2112/pen/NWYLMNx) demo showing both methods (full screen vid is not working with code snippets)

Edit: `fullscreenchange` now appears to work in Chrome 114.0.5735.199